# Limited WiFi access

Tags: internet-connection

I am experiencing issues with my WiFi connection on Windows 7 (64-bit).
Signal strength is fine, however, when attempting to access a secured network I get a ‘limited access’ error.

I have tried changing IP to static and back to DHCP, `ipconfig /flushdns`, `ipconfig /release` and `ipconfig /renew` - all failed.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `netsh winsock reset` then restart computer.
Are you using some third party antivirus ? Try to disable it completely.
If it does not help, try to disable and stop service `IP helper` then uncheck in property of wifi adapter IPv6 protocol.